PCL: How to figure out the corner points and its coordinates of an object using PCL
Since im new to PCL, im not sure how to proceed with my current task. I need to find the coordinates or vectors to the corner points. I used concave hull to make a boundary and now need to find out the relevant information such as the corner point coordinates. Need suggestions as to what i can use, algorithms etc. thanks.
Im dealing with 3D objects, for example, a block of wood. By corner points, i mean the points at the corners. After segmenting my object, the object is now flat in XY plane. Hence i would have 4 points.


Is your object 3D then? How do you define "corner points"? Can you give an example, or at least describe what objects you are dealing with?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If you have the hull of this now 2D object and know the ordering along the hull, you could just iterate along the points, compute the angle between the previous, current, and next point, and mark it as a "corner point" if the angle is sufficiently smaller than 180 degrees

Thanks it worked! On the same topic, I used Concave hull algo to get the hull but im not sure how exactly it works in PCL. I know how Concave Hull in general works but in PCL, we use Alpha to limit the size of the resultant hull segments. But i dont understand how its implemented. When i look at the source codes, its just way too complex. Do you know the implementation actually works?
